# MongoDB objectID stranger Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mean-stack, objectid

Using a MEAN Stack deployment on Heroku I am able to `GET` and `DELETE` Documents with mongoDB's `findOne` and `deleteOne` functions. However when I try to `PUT` a document with the mongoDB `updateOne`/`update` function, I receive this error (server side) :

> The _id field cannot be changed from {_id: ObjectId('56d4d71191fdc81100974d0b')} to {_id: "56d4d71191fdc81100974d0b"}.

Seems strange because I am using the same method in my server code for `updateOne` as in `findOne` (again, `findOne` works fine):

```
app.get("/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(req.params.id) }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(err.message, "Failed to get contact");
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(doc);
    }
  });
});

app.put("/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
  var updateDoc = req.body;
  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, updateDoc, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(err.message, "Failed to update contact");
    } else {
      res.status(204).end();
    }
  });
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're doing an update and your updated doc contains an _id, Mongo doesn't like that. Remove _id from updateDoc: `delete updateDoc._jd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have problem at `var updateDoc =  req.body`

As req.body contains id field and you are searching from object to update by that id, mongodb thinks you are trying to update
id field too which is not allowed.

One solution is to remove id field from your updateDoc object.
e.g.

```
delete updateDoc._id;
```

now try again and see if it works.

Your final function should look like

```
app.put("/contacts/:id", function(req, res) {
  var updateDoc = req.body;
  delete updateDoc.id;

  db.collection(CONTACTS_COLLECTION).updateOne({_id: new ObjectID(req.params.id)}, updateDoc, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      handleError(err.message, "Failed to update contact");
    } else {
      res.status(204).end();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. I had spent far too long on that